# Unable to update Data

Tags: javascript, rest, fetch-api, redux-saga

I am trying to update the JSON data through an API call.

I was able to GET the data without any issues, as am not passing any Options in the request.

For UPDATE,

//saga.js

```
export function* BlurideaTitler(opt) {
    const id = opt.id;  // 4
    const updatedTitle = opt.newTitle;   // "title changed"
    let options = {  
      crossDomain: true,
      method: 'PUT',
      json: true,
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
      body: {
        title: updatedTitle
      }
    };
   const requestURL = `http://localhost:3000/ideas/${id}`;

  try {
       yield call(request, requestURL, options);
  } catch (err) {
       console.log(err);
  }
}
```

// request.js

```
export default function request(url, options) {
  return fetch(url, options)
    .then(checkStatus)
    .then(parseJSON);
}
```

//db.json

JSON am trying to update.,

```
{
  "ideas": [
    {
      "id": 4,
      "title": "My fourth Idea",
      "body": "Description of my fourth idea",
      "created_date": "14-Apr-2019"
    }
  ]
}
```

This is supposed to update the value of title, but it throws error 'Bad request'. Can someone please let me know what am missing here?

Comment: first fix your body in your new request. Key should be in double quotes.
body: {
        "title": updatedTitle
      }

Comment: why you think it's a front end issue?